# Versioning multiple solutions with shared base assembly

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, versioning

I have a c# / Visual Studio design question which may seem basic, but it's been puzzling me on how to achieve my goal for a while without success...

I have several solutions sharing a common code base, which I added to a separate assembly referenced by my solutions.

I have made a git repository for the assembly itself as well as for the individual solutions, so when I create a release, I can create a restore point for both the base assembly and solution, in case I need hot fixes.

QUESTION: is there a way to create a single restore-point for both the base assembly and released solution, so I have full code backed-up at once and, in case it is needed, I can restore my backed-up files in one go?

Comment: Side notes: asking for tutorial is off-topic on SO (and that sentence is not necessary in your post altogether from my point of view); please don't add "thanks" and other text not directly related to problem (like "new to C#, site,...") to questions. If you feel that thank you are important to your question - please discuss it first on http://meta.stackoverflow.com (but consider reading http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it first).

Comment: How are you versioning the common code in your application code base? Are you using some packaging system like NuGet where the version number the application depends on will be declared in the packages.config/json? In that case, you don't really need to "tag" the common version when releasing the app. You can get the Common Version number from the App, and then lookup the matching "tag" in the Common code base.